# Returning the row number of a matched value in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, asp-classic

2I have a query which contains two fields (for the purposes of this example, anyway):-

```
RecordID
RecordDate
```

This table is sorted by RecordDate (ascending).

I would like to find out the position within that query of a specified value in RecordID.

So, for example, if my table contains the following:-

```
10    15/2/1989
11    15/3/1989
12    15/4/1989
13    15/5/1989
```

And my value is '11', then I want to return row number 2...is this something that is possible?

Comment: http://www.openwinforms.com/row_number_to_sql_select.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordDate) AS Row,
    RecordID, RecordDate 
from 
    YourTablename
```

You can add conditions then adding `where RecordId='11'` or @input